# Convert float to char array on ATtiny85

Tags: attiny85

I'm having a hard time trying to convert a float into a char array so it's stored like '7.125' just like the float looks.

I'm trying to communicate with an ATtiny85 (slave) and a program on a Raspberry Pi (master) over I2C.

The master expects 31 bytes from the slave when data is sent to it.

When I use this code on the ATtiny85 everything works as it should, the Pi gets the data correctly.

```
    char computerdata[35]; 
    computerdata[0] = '3';
    computerdata[1] = '.';
    computerdata[2] = '8';
    computerdata[3] = '7';
    computerdata[4] = '7';

    TinyWire.send(1);
    TinyWire.send(computerdata,30);
```

Of course I need to put a float variable in the array and not define numbers like I have for testing and this is where it breaks.

When I do something like this, it doesn't work, the Pi reports parsing error yet when I do this on the Due with Serial prints the char array looks good but something is different about it.

```
  sprintf(computerdata, "%2.32f", pH);

OR

  snprintf (computerdata, 35, "%f", pH);
```

What am I missing? Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to complement Michel Keijzers’ answer: `sprintf()` or `snprintf()`
are normally the right solution. On the AVR platform, however, float
conversions are left out of their default implementation, because they
take quite a lot of flash space, even when not used. On the other hand,
the avr-libc provides the non-standard function [`dtostrf()`](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdlib.html#ga060c998e77fb5fc0d3168b3ce8771d42)
for doing this conversion. The program

```cpp
void setup() {
    float f = 3.877;
    char str[35];
    dtostrf(f, 0, 3, str);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println(str);
}

void loop(){}
```

outputs

```
3.877
```

Comment: perfect, thank-you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the library which implements `snprintf` and `sprintf` can be dependent on the compiler used for your MCU, so in your case it's not supported.

If you always need the form `%2.32f` why not put it in directly, like:

```
int i = int(3.877 * 1000.0); // Assuming f of form a.bcd, i will be 3877
char str[6];
str[0] = (i / 1000) % 10; 
str[1] = '.';
str[2] = (i / 100) % 10;
str[3] = (i /  10) % 10;
str[4] = (i      ) % 10;
str[5] = '0';
```

It will be much faster too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that wouldn't compile, got this error. Edgar's worked good.  
sketch_feb28b.ino: In function 'void setup()':
sketch_feb28b:21: error: invalid operands of types 'double' and 'int' to binary 'operator%'
sketch_feb28b:22: error: invalid operands of types 'double' and 'int' to binary 'operator%'
invalid operands of types 'double' and 'int' to binary 'operator%'

Comment: True, I changed it, now it compiles (did not check it on an Arduino).
I will keep it despite `dtostrf`is better in most cases.

Comment: works good now. :)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation

Comment: On an attiny85, the real question is why you got a float in the beginning. :)

Comment: @DataFiddler Because you need one (?) … or do you mean it's normally better to avoid floats and multiply a float value to an integer with some specific digits (e.g. use an integer value * 1000, to have 3 digits in form a.bcd ?)

Comment: You convert the float to an int. Probably it became a float by `* 5.0 / 1023` or similar nonsense

Comment: @DataFiddler that's for the op to answer I guess.